# add uiview at row selection

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiview

I want when tab on row a `UIView` containing two button appear at the center of the cell, so I did the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //how can I get the text of the cell here?
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];

    v.center  = cell.center;

    UIButton*button1 =[[UIButton alloc] init];

    button1.frame = CGRectMake(v.center.x - 5 , v.center.y  , 5 , v.center.y + 4  );
    button1.titleLabel.text = @"I'm label 1";

    [v addSubview: button1];

    UIButton*button2 =[[UIButton alloc] init];

    button2.frame = CGRectMake(v.center.x - + 1 , v.center.y  , 5 , v.center.y + 4  );
    button2.titleLabel.text = @"I'm label 2";

    [v addSubview: button2];

    [cell addSubview:v];

    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}
```

`UIView` doesn't appear. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithFrame` is the designated initialiser for views.

Since you are using `init` it doesn't know how large a view to create.

Also `UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];` is incorrect. UIButtons are created with the `buttonWithType:` class method.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: v];
```

It should work.

Edit:
Try this code. Give the frames accordingly, it will work.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 100, 200, 200)];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[v addSubview:button];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.contentView addSubview:v];
```

Comment: i have edited the answer, i have tested it and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];//You have not set the frame of the v;
```